# How to suppress warning message from script when calling Set-ExecutionPolicy

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am writing a script to prepare our laptops before use. It essentially installs certificates and sets the executionpolicy to AllSigned.

It gets executed by right mouse click and "Run with Powershell". This is a windows 10 standard bypass of executionpolicy and lets the script run on unmodified windows 10 machines (That's what it looks like to me at least). So I can execute my script without the need to change the executionpolicy explicitly.
After the script ran the machine is set up. I just get a warning that I want to suppress.

To do this inside the script I elevate the script to administrator rights with a bypass parameter. This works fine except that **I get a warning when setting the AllSigned execution policy**. It says that I have a policy defined at a more specific scope.

Note: The command worked and the execution policy is set. It just pops up red and looks like an error. If someone else executes the script I don't want to have questions popping up.

--**My question:**--
As I know that this behavior is intended I don't want the warning from showing up. How can I suppress the message?

I tried various settings with the switches "WarningAction" and "ErrorAction" but it does not work.

Some Details:
ErrorMessage:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy
>   successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a
>   more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its
>   current effective execution policy of Bypass. Type
>   "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings.
>   For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy". At
>   C:\Users\uwe\Desktop\InstallRootCA\InstallRootCertificate.ps1:46
>   char:5
>   +     Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope LocalMachine -Force
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

Relevant Code parts from powershell script:

Elevating the script prior to execution:

```
 if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
     Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
     exit;
 }
```

Setting the Executionpolicy at the end of the script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope LocalMachine
```

I tried all kinds of flags

```
-Force
-WarningAction Ignore|SilentlyContinue
-ErrorAction same
```

But still the red warning pops up.

Comment: Error told you that PermissionDenied , for me command `-force` work good without any popups. PS run as administrator.

Comment: It is running as administrator. The elevation code restarts the script as administrator. But that is the problem. It creates a warning because of bypassing the policy. The code runs fine.

Comment: i tried set every policy with parameter `-force` and no one show warning,popups or somethnig else.

Comment: The warning only comes if you write a script with the elevation code first and set the execution policy inside the script. Whereas the LocalMachine Policy is set to Restricted before starting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put this command into a try catch statement. The catch statement will handle the errors and if it is empty, nothing will happen if `Set-ExecutionPolicy` throws an error.

```
try{
    Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope LocalMachine
}
catch {
    #Do Nothing
}
```

Please test it, let me know if it worked and if it did, please mark the post as the answer :)

Comment: That works. Didn't think of it as I thought the ErrorAction would handle that.

Comment: Thanks for your fast feedback. I am glad it worked. BTW. I don't know why ErrorAction doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Nicicalu, `-ErrorAction` only operates on _non-terminating_ errors, whereas the error at hand is a _terminating_ one (even though it shouldn't be).

Answer (score 4):

[Nicicalu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60541930/45375) is effective; let me add some background information:

**What `Set-ExecutionPolicy` emits in your case is a (statement-)*terminating error***, which is why it is **neither affected by `-ErrorAction` nor by `-WarningAction`**.

***Terminating* errors can only be handled via**:

- **[`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally)**, as shown in Nicicalu's answer.
- The - rarely used - **[`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap)** statement
- Confusingly, they *can* be *silenced and ignored* by **setting *preference variable* `$ErrorActionPreference` to `'SilentlyContinue'`**.

  - That is confusing, because **the seemingly equivalent `-ErrorAction` common *parameter* does *not* work**; that is, `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or `-ErrorAction Ignore` have *no* effect, because `-ErrorAction` is **designed to operate on *non-terminating* errors only.**

For a **comprehensive overview of PowerShell's complex error handling**, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

---

Taking a step back: **It doesn't make sense for `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to report an *error* in this scenario**, given that the command *still succeeded* in principle.

Emitting a *warning* would be more appropriate, as suggested in  [GitHub issue #12032](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12032).