# Powershell splatting: pass ErrorAction = Ignore in hash table

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, parameter-splatting

Here's a script to list directories / files passed on the command line -- recursively or not:

```
param( [switch] $r )
@gci_args = @{
  Recurse = $r
  ErrorAction = Ignore
}
$args | gci @gci_args
```

Now this does not work because Ignore is interpreted as a literal. What's the canonical way to pass an ErrorAction?

I see that both `"Ignore"` and (in PS7) `{ Ignore }` work as values, but neither seems to make a difference for my use case (bad file name created under Linux, which stops PS5 regardless of the ErrorAction, but does not bother PS7 at all). So I'm not even sure the parameter has any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use native type.

```
$ErrorActionPreference.GetType().FullName # System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference
```

So, use

```
$gci_args = @{   
  Recurse = $r
  ErrorAction = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Ignore
}
```

Comment: Nice. How can you discover `$ErrorActionPreference`, or do you have to know about it beforehand?

Comment: @AldIn I think didn't got your question right. `$ErrorActionPreference` is built-in variable in powershell that is used by default if no `-ErrorAction` argument supplied. Same for `$WarningPreference` (for `-WarningAction`), `$InformationPreference` (for `-InformationAction`, **introduced in Powershell 3 I think**), `$DebugPreference`, and `$VerbosePreference`

Comment: To know current `$ErrorActionPreference` you just can read `$ErrorActionPreference` like `$oldEAP = $ErrorActionPreference`, change it, do something and change it back then `$ErrorActionPreference = $oldEap`

Comment: So, you have to know about this built-in beforehand. Which I do -- but somehow I didn't make the variable type connection. Thanks.

Comment: It's in the doc `about_preference_variables`

Comment: For slightly less verbosity, you can also write `[Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Ignore`, as the `System` namespace is implied.

Answer (score 4):

> because `Ignore` is interpreted as a literal

No, **`Ignore` is interpreted *as a command to execute***, because it is parsed in *argument mode* (command invocation, like a shell) rather than in *expression mode* (like a traditional programming language) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) for more information.

While using a [`[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference) enumeration value *explicitly*, as in [filimonic's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66124058/45375), is definitely an option, you can take advantage of the fact that **PowerShell automatically converts back and forth between `enum` values and their symbolic *string* representations**.

Therefore, **you can use *string* `'Ignore'`** as a more convenient alternative to `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Ignore`:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$gci_args = @{
  # ... 
  ErrorAction = 'Ignore'
}
```

<sup>Note that it is the *quoting* (`'...'`) that signals to PowerShell that *expression-mode* parsing should be used, i.e. that the token is a *string literal* rather than a command.</sup>

Also note that `-ErrorAction` only operates on *non-terminating* errors (which are the typical kind, however) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549569/45375) for more information.

---

As for **discovery** of the permissible `-ErrorAction` values:

- The conceptual [`about_CommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) help topic covers all *common parameters*, of which `-ErrorAction` is one.
- Many common parameters have corresponding *preference variables* (which accept the same values), covered in [`about_Preference_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables), which allow you to *preset* common parameters.
- *Interactively*, you can use *tab-completion* to see the permissible values (as unquoted symbolic names, which you simply need to wrap in quotes); e.g.:

  ```
  # Pressing the Tab key repeatedly where indicated 
  # cycles through the acceptable arguments.
  Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction <tab>
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Note that using a string does *not* mean giving up type safety, if the context unambiguously calls for a specific `enum` type, such as in this case. Validation only happens *at runtime* either way, given that PowerShell is an *interpreted* language.

However, it is possible for a PowerShell-aware *editor* - such as Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension - to flag incorrect values at *design time*. As of version `2020.6.0`, however, that does *not* yet appear to be the case. Fortunately, however, *tab-completion* and IntelliSense work as expected, so the problem may not arise.

That said, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, in the context of defining a hashtable entry for latter splatting the expected type is not (yet) known, so explicit use of `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]` does have advantages: (a) IntelliSense in the editor can guide you, and (b) - assuming that [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher is in effect - an invalid value will we reported *earlier* at runtime, namely *at the point of assignment*, which makes troubleshooting easier. As of PowerShell 7.1, a caveat regarding `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is that you will not be able to use the intrinsic (PowerShell-supplied) `.Count` property on objects that don't have it type-natively, due to the bug described in [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798).</sup>