# Use PowerShell to handle errors generated by a Java CLI application

Tags: java, powershell

I using PowerShell to call a Java CLI application.

I'd like to be able to capture Java errors and handle them in PowerShell.  I'm simulating this by trying to get the version of Java.

If I use a valid argument (`--version`)

```
# --version - print product version to the output stream and exit
Start-Process -FilePath java -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '--version' -RedirectStandardOutput ~\Desktop\stdout.txt
```

`stdout.txt` contains the expected text:

```
Get-Content  ~\Desktop\stdout.txt
openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.3+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.3+7, mixed mode)
```

If I use an invalid argument (`-v`)

```
# -v; invalid argument
Start-Process -FilePath java -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '-v' -RedirectStandardError ~\Desktop\stderr.txt
```

`stderr.txt` contains the expected text:

```
Get-Content ~\Desktop\stderr.txt
Unrecognized option: -v
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work in a try/catch block:

```
try {
    # exception isn't raised
    Start-Process -FilePath java -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '-v' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Host "ERROR: $( $_.Exception.Message )" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work as I would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to *synchronously* execute console applications (such as `java`), *in the current console window*, including the ability to *directly* capture their output, call them *directly*, do *not* use `Start-Process` (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375). [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of  `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

Thus, for synchronous execution use the following, which:

- directly prints stderr output (as well as stdout output), while also allowing it to be suppressed (`2>$null`) or redirected to a file (`2>stderr.txt`), or mixed into the stdout / success output stream (`2>&1`).

  - Note: It would be helpful if stderr output could be captured in a *variable*, with syntax such as `2>variable:stderr`, which isn't supported as of PowerShell 7.2.x - see [GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332).
- reports the console application process' *exit code* in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode); given that stderr output isn't only used for actual *errors*, but also for other *non-data* purposes, such as status information, success vs. failure of a call to an external (console) application should only ever be inferred from whether `$LASTEXITCODE` is `0` (indicates success) or is nonzero (indicates failure, by convention).

```bash
# Invokes java synchronously with arguments, in the current console window.
# Prints both stdout and stderr to the console, unless you capture or redirect it.
java -v
# $LASTEXITCODE now contains the process exit code.
# $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0  tells you if the call succeeded.
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Since you're using `Start-Process` *without `-Wait`*, the execution is *asynchronous*, so you cannot know the *full* content of the stdout and stderr streams until after the `java` process has exited.
- As stated, only the process exit code should be used to determine success vs. failure, which would require you to add `-PassThru` in order to obtain that exit code from the `.ExitCode` property of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance that is then returned - assuming you either used `-Wait` too or have first ensured that the `.HasExited` property returns `$true`.
- Applying `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Start-Process` is unrelated to whether *the application invoked* reports an error.

  - In fact, even if `Start-Process` fails to even *find* the specified executable and therefore fundamentally cannot even *invoke* it, it will report a statement-*terminating* error, to which the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) does *not* apply - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549569/45375) for details.
  - It is only *if invocation itself fails* that a [`try { ... } catch { ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) would take effect (independently of the `-ErrorAction` argument).

---

As for **what you're probably looking for - *quietly* capturing *stderr* output**:

- Using a file to capture stderr output.

```bash
java -v 2>~\Desktop\stderr.txt
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  Write-Host "ERROR: $(Get-Content -Raw ~\Desktop\stderr.txt)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

- If you want to avoid use of a file:

```bash
$stdout, $stderr = (java -v 2>&1).Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split' })

$stdout # Output collected stdout lines.

if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  Write-Host "ERROR: $stderr" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

- If you want to avoid use of a file and *stream* stdout output (rather than collect it in full first and *then* output):

```bash
$stderr = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

java -v 2>&1 | 
  ForEach-Object { if ($_ -is [string]) { $_ } else { $stderr.Add($_) } }

if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  Write-Host "ERROR: $stderr" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: I see that `$LASTEXITCODE` is 1 indicating a failure, but how do I get `stderr` to be captured in a try/catch block?  It doesn't do me any good to have it written to the console.

Comment: @craig, please see my update (bottom section, but also other parts); try / catch is the wrong tool in this case.

Comment: I was figuring that I'd need to read the content of a redirected file; you confirmed that suspicion.

Comment: @craig, not necessarily - please see my update.

Comment: @craig, the last, streaming solution would allow you to use `throw` on encountering the first stderr line, which in turn would allow you to use `try { ... } catch { ... }`, but, as stated, it's better to let the process exit and check `$LASTEXITCODE` afterwards.

Comment: I like your second answer.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @craig; my pleasure.