# Powershell console output to variable

Tags: powershell, variables, curl, console

I got a powershell script for a url get query. I use the external curl.exe because Invoke-Webrequest and the .NET is not able to query with GET and with a body.

I just need the http response code.

```
$header = "Bearer ABCDE"
$ContentType = "application/json"
$url = "http://test/api"

$bodyJson='{""SSELECT1"": ""0"", ""SSELECT2"": ""TEST1""}'
$pattern = "(?<=HTTP/1.1 )\d+"

$output =  & "C:\curl\bin\curl.exe" -X GET -H "Authorization: $header" -H "Content-Type: $ContentType" -d $bodyJson -v $url

Write-Host "Response: " $output

$httpCode = [regex]::Match($output, $pattern).Groups[1].Value

Write-Host "HTTP CODE: " $httpCode
```

This is the output I need in a Variable to catch the http code, but its only shown in the powershell console. But the output variable conains just the line at the bottom "Response: XYZ", so I have just access to the curl result. Is there any way?

```
curl.exe :   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
    In Zeile:9 Zeichen:15
    + ... usgabe =  $(&"C:\curl\bin\curl.exe" -X GET -H "Authorization: $header ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (  % Total    % ...  Time  Current:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
     
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Host XY was resolved.
    * IPv6: (none)
    * IPv4: 123
    *   Trying 123...
    * Connected to celle (123) port xy
    > GET test/api HTTP/1.1
    > Host: 123
    > User-Agent: curl/8.6.0
    > Accept: */*
    > Authorization: Bearer ABCDE
    > Content-Type: application/json
    > Content-Length: 57
    > 
    } [57 bytes data]
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Content-Type: application/json
    < Content-Length: 278
    < Date: Thu, 14 Mar 2024 12:15:58 GMT
    < 
    { [278 bytes data]
    100   335  100   278  100    57   2989    613 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3764
    * Connection #0 to host XY left intact
```

Output:

```
Response:  {"records":[{"value":{"TEST":"1","TEST2":"2"}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The *general* answer to your question is to append [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `2>&1` to your `curl.exe` call, causing PowerShell to capture *stderr* output too (which is where `curl.exe` prints its progress and verbose information to, alongside error messages).

  - If you later need to separate stdout lines from stderr lines in the combined output, use the technique shown in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833157/45375).
- The *specific* solution, for [`curl`](https://curl.se/), given that you're interested in *only* the HTTP status code:

```
$output = 
  C:\curl\bin\curl.exe -s -w '%{http_code}' -X GET -H "Authorization: $header" -H "Content-Type: $ContentType" -d $bodyJson $url -o /dev/null
```

- `-s` (`--silent`) silences progress and error output.
- `-w '%{http_code}'` outputs the HTTP status code on an extra line, after the response body.
- `-o /dev/null` *discards* the response body, so that in effect only the HTTP status code prints.

  - Remove this argument if you want to capture the response body too.

    - You can then separate the response body from the status code as follows:

      ```
       $responseBody, $statusCode = 
         ($output | select -SkipLast 1), $output[-1]
      ```
  - Note that `/dev/null` isn't actually the null device on Windows and is treated like a literal path that causes an *error*; however, this error can be ignored and effectively *is* ignored, due to `-s`; a proper, but *Windows-only* solution would be to target `NUL` (on Unix-like platforms you'd create an output file *literally* named `NUL` in the current directory).

Answer (score 0):

The return object from `Invoke-WebRequest` should have the status code as a property and can also take the body data as an argument.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $header -Body $body -ContentType application/json

$statusCode = $response.StatusCode
```

Comment: Note the premise of the question: "I use the external `curl.exe` because `Invoke-Webrequest` and the .NET is not able to query with `GET` and with a body."