# Trouble Executing Code Inside a PowerShell 'Trap' Block

Tags: powershell, trap

I have a function that runs, and within this function, I've implemented a `trap`. However, it doesn't execute the code inside the `trap`. Instead, it writes an error message as expected, but it doesn't apply resource locks as intended. I can see that there are 7 `LockObjects` when it throws the error by printing the count, but is it possible to make it execute the code?

Here's the code:

```
# In case an error occurs, we will apply the locks back to the subscriptions
trap {
    Write-Error "$($LockObjects.count)"
    Write-Error $_
    foreach ($LockObject in $LockObjects) {
        Set-ResourceLock -SubscriptionId $LockObject.subscriptionId -Action Add -InputLocks $LockObject.LockObject
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why the code within the `trap` block isn't being executed as expected, and how I can ensure it applies the resource locks correctly when an error occurs?

Comment: i have implemented a "throw" to make sure it stops and it does fail and give my a 7 as error message, but it does not execute the foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a general note:

- `trap` - like `try` / `catch` - only operates on *terminating* errors, whereas *non-terminating* ones are far more typical. To convert the latter to terminating ones, use either `-ErrorAction Stop` or set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` first. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549569/45375) for background information.

---

You state that the `trap` block *is* executed in your case, yet only *part of it* is executed.

The likeliest explanation is:

- You have `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in effect.
- As a result, your use of [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error) *aborts the `trap` script block too*.

The following simplified example illustrates this problem:

```bash
function foo {
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  trap {
    Write-Error $_
    # !! THIS CODE IS NEVER REACHED.
    Write-Host 'After Write-Error.'
  }
  # Provoke an error
  1 / 0
}

foo
```

Note:

- You don't need `Write-Error $_` in your `trap` block in order to print the error at hand: Unless you use `continue` to exit, it will print *automatically*, albeit *after* the `trap` block has executed - see the conceptual [about_Trap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) help topic.
- If you want to use `Write-Error` for other reasons, add `-ErrorAction Continue` to prevent the `trap` block from being aborted.

Comment: thank you! i removed the write-error and it worked

Comment: Glad to hear it, @NadiaHansen.